# Assigning member function to callback with boost::bind and boost::function

Tags: c++, boost

I am trying to assign a member function as the callback to an API method, but it return the below error message, I am not sure how to resolve this.

```
cannot convert ‘boost::function<int(rcv_t_stct*, msg_t_stct*)>*’ to ‘rcv_cb {aka int (*)(rcv_t_stct*, msg_t_stct*)}’
```

callback signature:

```
typedef int (*rcv_cb)(rcv_t *rcv, msg_t *msg);
```

callback setter:

```
create(rcv_cb cb);
```

my member function:

```
int receiver::on_received(rcv_t *rcv, msg_t *msg)
{
    return 0;
}
```

attempted to assign to the setter:

```
boost::function<int (rcv_t *, msg_t *)> f2( boost::bind( &receiver::on_received, this, _1, _2) ); 
create(f2);
```

**Solution:**

I changed the receiver class to singleton, and used a static member function to wrap the non-static one.

```
int receiver::on_received(rcv_t *rcv, msg_t *msg)
{
    return receiver::instance().on_received_private(rcv, msg);
}
```

Is this the best solution it can be to resolve this issue?

Comment: can you change callback signature `boost::function<int(rcv_t_stct*, msg_t_stct*)>`?

Comment: no i can't. it is a third party library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `boost::function<>` is not a free function, but a functor (type implementing `operator()`). You cannot convert from `boost::function<S>` to a pointer to a function with the signature `S`. If it is within your control, you can change the callback setter to take a `boost::function<>` rather than a free function. If that is outside of your control, then you cannot use a non-static member function for the callback.

Comment: So i have to create a static member function in my class?

Comment: @BryanFok: Or a free function, but you cannot use a non-static member function.